# Atualizando apenas as propriedades enviadas - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou tentando abstrair os métodos para salvar/atualizar os dados das minhas models. Fiz uma rotina genérica para abstrair essa operação mas estou com um probleminha. No cenário abaixo eu tenho a model `Pessoa` e no meu controller da web-api eu a recebo, só que ao invés de mandar todas as propriedades da classe eu mandei um JSON com apenas as propriedades que vão ser atualizadas. O problema é que o Entity tenta atualizar tudo inclusive as propriedades não enviadas.

> Pessoa

```
class Pessoa {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public String Nome { get; set; }
   public String Email { get; set; }
}
```

Supondo que eu tenha na tabela pessoa um registro com id "31" e eu queira enviar o json abaixo, o Entity iria dar um erro falando que e-mail não pode ser `null` mas eu só quero atualizar apenas o nome e queria isso de forma automática sem ter que ficar implementando classe a classe. Alguém já passou por isso? Obrigado.

> Exemplo do JSON

```
{
    "id": 34,
    "nome": "Hiago"
}
```

Comment: Isso é em todo projeto?

Comment: Sim @VirgilioNovic na realidade estou criando uma arquitetura padrão para implementar nos meus projetos. Ai estou abstraindo essas coisas com métodos de beforeUpdate, afterUpdate essas coisas, para evitar repetição de código.

Comment: Acho que da forma que trabalha o EF não faz isso

Comment: Então Virgilio, eu consegui fazer.. Mas não gostei da solução, pois eu informo se a propriedade foi alterada ou não usando o dbEntityEntry.Property(property.Name).IsModified mas para saber se a propriedade foi alterada eu checo o null ou então o 0 no caso dos INT e isso não é confiável pois eu posso realmente querer enviar null no serviço ou então 0 em alguma propriedade.

Comment: Olha talvez utilizar reflexão mas não sei se é uma boa. Tem que ver se vale apena. Ou algum pacote que faça isso se acha algo posto

Answer (score 1):

O que você tem que fazer nesses caso, na API você recebe o ID do objeto que deseja atualizar certo? Então você teria que fazer as seguintes etapas, vou criar um cenário aqui.

Esse é seu modelo (exemplo):

```
class Pessoa{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Ai na API você receba (JSON) para atualizar apenas o nome:

```
{
     "Id" : 1,
     "Nome" : "Atualização"
}
```

você terá que fazer a seguinte ação, buscar no banco o objeto referente a esse ID:

```
var pessoa = contexto.Pessoa.First(x => x.Id == model.Id);
```

atualizar apenas o campo que você deseja nesse requisição (isso garante que caso a propriedade Nome do model que veio via JSON seja null, mantenha o valor anterior):

```
pessoa.Nome = model.Nome ?? pessoa.Nome;
```

é depois e só salvar no banco de dados:

```
contexto.SalveChanges();
```

Caso você coloque valores nulo no objeto que será salvo o EF-Core não consegue identificar que não deveria (tentar) gravar esse registro no banco, a validação se o campo e nulo ou não e uma "regra de negócio" e tem que ser validada antes do `SaveChanges()` o que o EF-Core faz e colocar `NOT NULL` impedido a gravação, caso isso seja configurado na criação do banco de dados.